# How to change panel image and color theme in jquery mobile

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I've been trying to change the image of the panel button and the colors of the menu but I have been unsuccessful.  I would like the panel button blend in with the header similar to the one on the facebook mobile app.  Also I would like to be able to change the text color and background color of the overlay menu (menu divider and menu option "news").  Can someone please help me with this.  Thanks in advance.

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="home">
        <div data-role="header"  data-position="fixed">
            <a data-controltype="panelbutton" data-role="button" data-theme="b" href="#panel_menu" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" ></a>
            <h1>My App</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="panel" id="panel_menu" data-position="left" data-display="overlay" data-theme="b">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="a" data-inset="false">
                <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading"> Menu </li>
                <li data-theme="c"> <a href="" data-transition="turn">News</a> </li>     
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>Footer Text</h1>
        </div>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check this link http://themeroller.jquerymobile.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<body>
        <div data-role="page" id="home">
        <div data-role="header"  data-position="fixed">
            <a id="custom-button" class="custom-button" data-controltype="panelbutton" data-role="button" data-theme="b" href="#panel_menu" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" ></a>
            <h1>My App</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="panel" id="panel_menu" data-position="left" data-display="overlay" data-theme="b">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="a" data-inset="false">
                <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading"> Menu </li>
                <li data-theme="c"> <a href="" data-transition="turn">News</a> </li>     
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>Footer Text</h1>
        </div>
    </div> 
    </body>
```

CSS:

```
#custom-button{
  background: transparent;
}
.custom-button{
background:transparent!important;
}
```

Explanation:

Every element that you need to write custom styles you can ad an id, like in case of the a element, i have added an custom-button id. Keep in mind id must be unique, one per page. and every style added to id will automatically override any class style.
You can also add classes to already existing once, but use !important hack to override existing styles.